# How do I add or change the class attribute of a JSF dataTable (primefaces)?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have a [PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf) and I want to specify a CSS class in the generated HTML `<table>` element. If I use the `styleClass` attribute, then this will be added to the wrapping `<div>` instead of the `<table>`. How can I get it on the `<table>` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set `tableStyle` or `tableStyleClass` attribute, it will add the css class to the table element.