# Add css-class to primefaces datatable <table>-element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to combine Bootstrap 3 and Primefaces 4. I've tried to add

```
 styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"
```

to a PrimeFaces . These classes are not added to the html table-element, and hence it doesn't get "Bootstrapped". They are added to a surronding div.

[image: table element has no class attribute]

I've tried the Primefaces Bootstrap theme, it is not very responsive.

I would be happy if anyone could provide me with a simple way to get these classes to the  element... Can you?

Comment: Sorry, did not find this question before I posted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266895/how-do-i-add-or-change-the-class-attribute-of-a-jsf-datatable-primefaces?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see Primefaces generates its components based on it own rules. So it can have its own outer and inner elements.

Try using `tableStyleClass="..."`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer was simpler than I thought... Just used this jquery-snippet:

```
 $('#aTable table').addClass("table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed");
```

Resulted in

[image]

Comment: Also, I see this answer is even better and simpler.... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266895/how-do-i-add-or-change-the-class-attribute-of-a-jsf-datatable-primefaces?rq=1

Comment: Nice find.. saw this after I answered.